# SQLite INNER JOIN - How to output only one of the common columns the two tables have

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-sqlite, natural-join

Let's say that I have two tables:

1. **lessons** with columns: lessonID, name
2. **studentlessons** with columns: lessonID, age

I am trying to perform this action:

```
SELECT lessons.*, studentlessons.* FROM studentlessons   
JOIN lessons WHERE studentlessons.lessonID = lessons.lessonID
```

but the result is a table which have the columns:

> lessonID, name, lessonID(1), age

I want to avoid the lessonID(1), so my desired output must be:

> lessonID, name, age

I know that I can use this syntax:

```
SELECT lessons.lessonID, lessons.name, studentlessons.age FROM studentlessons   
JOIN lessons WHERE studentlessons.lessonID = lessons.lessonID
```

but I can't because of some other reasons.

Is there any purely SQLite syntax that can give me my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM studentlessons NATURAL JOIN lessons
```

which returns only one of the columns `lessonID`. 
The tables are joined implicitly on the columns that have the same name(s).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=daaffa1bd8ea0469c4bfe9eb02b1b832).

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work

Comment: @Student the code is syntactically correct and as you can see in the demo it returns the columns that you want. What didn't work?

Comment: I just tried this code in Android Studio and in SqliteStudio and it returned the lessonID:1 column .

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise that it doesn't need the WHERE clause. It worked, thanks!